# How to speed up Vec<bool> in my Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Tags: optimization, vector, rust

Why is this straight forward implementation of sieve in Rust so slow and how to speed it up?

```
use std::num::Float;
use std::iter::range_step;

fn eratosthenes(n: uint) -> Vec<bool> {
    let mut sieve = Vec::from_elem(n+1,true);

    sieve[0] = false;
    sieve[1] = false;

    let m = ((n as f64).sqrt()) as uint;

    for i in range(0u, m+1) {
        if sieve[i] {
            for j in range_step(i*i, n+1, i) {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    sieve
}

fn main() {
    eratosthenes(100_000_000);
    /*    
    let mut found = Vec::new();
    for (i,&sieve) in sieve.iter().enumerate() {
        if sieve {
            found.push(i);
        }
    }
    println!("Primes found: {}",found.len());
    */
}
```

P.S.: I am not asking about a better algorithm but how to use Vec (Slice?) properly to make this decently fast!

Comment: Compile with `-O`

Comment: I'd use a set containing the found numbers. Other than that, use a profiler to find out what takes the most time.

Comment: Compilation with -O makes it about 13 times faster and brings it into the range I had expected! So is that the trick?  No "better use some other types / slices instead of what you did?". @UlrichEckhardt I think a set will be slower. It may save memory though.

Comment: Also note that access to vector elements by index always includes boundary checks. For large numbers it may cause some overhead.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev OK, but what alternatives exists to that (besides using 'unsafe' I guess)?

Comment: There are methods for unchecked indexing, but the do require `unsafe`. I suggest you only drop to using them only as a last resort. *The* proper way to access vector elements without bounds checking is iterators, but I don't see how they could be used here.

Comment: You can use a `std::collections::Bitv` which is effectively a `Vec<bool>` that packs the booleans into individual bits, cutting memory use 8 times, which dramatically improves cache behaviour.

Comment: @dbaupp rewriting it with Bitv was trivial. It is slightly faster than the Vec<bool> for the original 100,000,000 and uses a lot less memory. For comparison (on my machine) using 1,000,000,000 as target the original source (with -O) uses 1,001 GB Mem and about 10 seconds. The Bitv version uses 126 MB an 7,9 seconds. Switching to unsafe indexing in my original code did nearly nothing at all. If I did it right that is (`unsafe { *sieve.unsafe_mut(j)=true; }`).

Comment: @OderWat sounds like you should sum all this up as a self-answer!

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, I guess I will do that. Currently I am still trying out some stuff and even the new nightly "asked" me to change the code (again) :)